# Javascript Date() sometimes returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, date

Sometimes while using this constructor I am getting incorrect values:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

I'm sure it is something I'm doing incorrectly, but can't see it.  This is what I'm doing:

I have an array with month, day, and year indexes like this

```
["02", "29", "2015"]
```

Then I am making a Date object like this

```
date = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[0] - 1, dateArray[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

When I print the date object to the console, I get this:

```
Sun Mar 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

Sometimes however it works as expected.  Using this array:

```
["03", "15", "2015"]
```

I get this:

```
Sun Mar 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)
```

Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there *is* no February 29 in 2015! That's not a leap year. The day after February 28 is March 1st. This is the expected behavior.

The precise behavior is defined in [§15.9.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.5) of the ECMAScript 5.1 specification.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, month is 0-based, so if you call `Date.getMonth()`, you get a value between `0 - 11`, `Date.getDate()` returns day of the month between `1 - 31`, `Date.getDay()` returns day of the week between `0 - 6` with `0` for `Sunday`. So in your case, the month `02` is march, but you minus it by `1` which results in `01` which is February and depends on leap year, you have 29 days or not. Because the year is `2015`, February is only 28 days, but you specified 29 for the day, that is why month is rolled over to `March 01`